# Why does Glorfindel have a saddle?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, elves

In FotR I, ch. XII, Glorfindel mentions his saddle:

> 'You shall ride my horse,' said Glorfindel. 'I will shorten the stirrups up to the saddle-skins, and you must sit as tight as you can.

Later in the novel, it is said at least twice that I have found with a quick `ctrl + F` that the Elves ride bareback, including when Gandalf calls it "elf-fashion" (bk. III, Ch. XI).
Why, then, does Glorfindel use a saddle?

Comment: *"The Noldor in Beleriand also used saddles. Curufin is noted as a strong and cunning horseman as he lifts Luthien to his saddle. A saddle provides a much more secure seat for anyone involved in fighting for horseback. It could be explained that Elves who were contemplating that type of activity would use saddles."* - http://forum.barrowdowns.com/showthread.php?t=1444

Comment: Also, Glorfindel may simply have thought ahead and realized that a saddle might be needed for a non-Elf.

Comment: *"But actually bridle was
casually and carelessly used for what I
suppose should have been called a
headstall.1 Or rather, since bit was added
(1221) long ago (Chapter 112 was written
very early) I had not considered the natural
ways of elves with animals. Glorfindel's
horse would have an ornamental headstall,
carrying a plume, and with the straps
studded with jewels and small bells; but
Glor. would certainly not use a bit. I will
change bridle and bit to headstall.* - Tolkien / Letters

Comment: @Valorum yes, I've read *Letters*, and my edition of LotR says "headstall" instead of "bridle", but that letter doesn't mention the saddle

Comment: Glorf rode in Human fashion.

Comment: Maybe Noldor specifically use saddles? Their culture always seemed quite different from the other elven races.

Comment: He was sent out specifically by Elrond to look for the party, and as such would likely have carried some supplies and possibly some additional weapons, and that's a lot easier with something to attach them to than trying to carry everything while riding bareback.

Comment: On the note of Curufin, is there any similar reference to Lúthien or Beleg using saddles at some point? (When riding horses that is, not Huan)

Comment: @Amarth Both Lúthien and Beleg were Sindar.

Comment: @Spencer Yes and so any reference to them riding in a saddle would prove my theory that it might be a Noldor thing wrong (Curufin and Glorfindel being Noldor).

Comment: Out of universe explanation. In some respects it is a fairy tale. Plot flaws are allowed to make a story possible. Why did a Balrog with wings fall into the chasm instead of fly? Why can the Rings of Power keep men in Arda when the Gift of Illuvator cannot be withheld even by the Vala. How do farms grow any crops in Morder where ashes block out the sun?

Comment: In universe. It says that elves of Valinor and especially the Noldor were more like men in physical stature. The elves of MEs' spirits gradually consumed their bodies and they were smaller pixie-like figures who didn't need saddles. I doubt a Noldo could have walked on top of snow the way Legolas did. I think of a ME elf as maybe 5'3" (1.6m) and 110lbs (49kg) but incredibly agile. I think of a Noldo as 5'10" (1.8m) and 160lbs (72kg)